# Java - Allow custom constraint to be null

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, null

I have the following custom constraint for an optional field, meaning it can be null or not. If it's null, I dont want to check it but if it has a value I want to check it. My constraints code is:

**Cif**

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CifValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface Cif {
    String message() default "Invalid cif";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**CifValidator**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class CifValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Cif, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Cif constraintAnnotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String cif, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSUVW])(\\d{7})([0-9A-J])$");

        if (!cif.matches(p.pattern()))
            return false;
        else
            return isValidCif(cif);
    }

    private boolean isValidCif(String cif) {
        System.out.println("haha");
        if (cif == null || cif.length() != 9)
            return false;

        String cifLetter = cif.substring(0, 1);

        if (!cifLetter.matches("[A-Z]"))
            return false;

        String cifDigits = cif.substring(1, cif.length() - 1);
        int sum = 0, digit;

        for (int i = 0; i < cifDigits.length(); ++i) {
            digit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(cifDigits.charAt(i)));

            if (!cifDigits.matches("\\d+"))
                return false;

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                digit *= 2;
                if (digit > 9)
                    digit = (digit / 10) + (digit % 10);

                sum += digit;
            } else
                sum += digit;
        }

        sum %= 10;
        if (sum != 0)
            digit = 10 - sum;
        else
            digit = sum;

        char[] letters = {'J', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'};
        String cifControlCharacter = cif.substring(cif.length() - 1);

        if (cifLetter.matches("[ABEH]"))
            return Integer.toString(digit).equalsIgnoreCase(cifControlCharacter);
        else if (cifLetter.matches("[NPQRSW]"))
            return Character.toString(letters[digit]).equalsIgnoreCase(cifControlCharacter);
        else
            return Integer.toString(digit).equalsIgnoreCase(cifControlCharacter) || Character.toString(letters[digit]).equalsIgnoreCase(cifControlCharacter);
    }
}
```

Is there a clean way to achieve this? I don't think just checking if its `null` with an `if` and returning `true` is cool. I think this is a dirty workarround tho and idk if there's something cleaner.

If I don't send the value to which I'm applying this constraint, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at es.xx.hos.xx.rest.validators.CifValidator.isValid(CifValidator.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at es.xx.hos.xx.rest.validators.CifValidator.isValid(CifValidator.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in you code, `isValid` method is executed before `isValidCif` thus `isValid` method should check the provided String variable if it's not null.

You can use `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(variable);`

before you get to this statement

```
if (!cif.matches(p.pattern()))
```

because if `cif` is null here you get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Hi, I know I could fix it just by checking if it's null and returning true if it is. But I'd like to know if there's a better way than that.

Comment: you can use Optional from java 8.
Optional.of(yourObject);
yourObjectAsOptional.isPresent()

Comment: but I'd have to do that still in isValid(), it's the saem as 'return true' to me , isn't there some kind of annotation for the interface or something?

Comment: you can you @NonNull from lombok, but this will still throw a null pointer exception